# Why does an itemize environment changes the leftbar color at page break?

Tags: color, page-breaking, itemize

I'm having some trouble using `leftbar` environment at the end of a page. It seems that when it contains an `itemize` environment that ends right before the pagebreak, the color of the associated `leftbar` is turned into another color than the right one (blue instead of green here).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, portrait]{geometry} % format de la page

\usepackage[french]{babel} % franciser le document (règles de typographie française)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % améliore césures et le copié-collé dans les pdf
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % codage d'entrée du fichier

\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{framed, color}

\usepackage[outerbars,color]{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\defbar}[1]{
  \cbcolor{green}
  \begin{changebar}
    \noindent\underline{Définition :} #1
  \end{changebar}
    \vspace{.4cm}
  }

\newcommand{\exebar}[1]{
  \cbcolor{blue}
  \begin{changebar}
    \noindent\underline{Exemple :} #1
  \end{changebar}
    \vspace{.4cm}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{16}{16} \textbf{Chapitre 1 : Algèbre générale et arithmétique}
\end{center}

\hrule

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\section{Les groupes}

\subsection{Structure de groupe}

\defbar{\lipsum[2] \lipsum[2]}

\exebar{\lipsum[2]}

\defbar{\lipsum[3-4]}

\exebar{\lipsum[4] \lipsum[6]}

\defbar{\lipsum[6] \lipsum[6]

Just another line.}

\subsection{Sous-groupe}

\defbar{Here is a new one-line text.

\begin{itemize}
\item The itemize that breaks it all.
\end{itemize}

Some extra-line.}

\exebar{Some property.}

\exebar{Some theorem.}

\end{document}
```

As you should see with that example, the leftbar at the end of the page is blue before the pagebreak (instead of green) and then green.

I've been thinking about this issue for a while now, and all I could find out is that :

- the colorbar problem is due to both the pagebreak AND the `itemize` environment at the pagebreak (replace it with a line of text and the blue bar goes green) ;
- for some reason, the color of that leftbar is linked to the next leftbar environment (if you change the next \exebar to \defbar the bar color turns green).

My questions are the following: why is the colorbar changing? What should I do in order to prevent it from changing?

Alex.

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour you describe. However, when removing the subsection, the colorbars all appear in the right way. Thus I think: The problem is not about the `itemize` but about the page break.

Comment: The color is not reset correctly at the page break, that's the problem!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Tiuri: You're right, the problem is actually related to both page break and the itemize that is contained in the leftbar environment (if you replace the itemize by a normal line, the color change should go away).

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I agree with you. Then, the question is: why isn't the color reset correctly at the page break? What should be done to get the right color right before the page break?

Comment: @Alex: Actually, no. I tested replacing the `itemize` by just a simple text line, and the color of the bar still changed. So I assume it is not related to itemize at all.

Comment: @Tiuri I don't know why but when i replace it by 1 or 2 lines and compile the source on my computer, the colorbar gets green as expected (that's not really important because i don't want to get rid off the `itemize`; still, this is quite intriguing....)

Comment: Of course it is important, because we need to think about whether it is something in `itemize` that breaks the colorbars, or whether we just have to look into `changebar`s code. So [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMQdi.png) my output.

Comment: Well, I was saying that this might be unimportant because it feels like it is computer-depending or something like that... (my output is [here](https://i.imgur.com/ez0OuYW.png) ) Do you have an idea why are your leftbars so far away from text compared to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide a bypass - solution, not using `changebar` but the powerful `tcolorbox` package with its `breakable` boxes and `borderline` options.

[image]

The shifting of the 'bars' can be controlled with `barshiftleft`, the bar colors with `defbarcolor=` and `exebarcolor=`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, portrait]{geometry} % format de la page

\usepackage[french]{babel} % franciser le document (règles de typographie française)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % améliore césures et le copié-collé dans les pdf
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % codage d'entrée du fichier


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif


\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\barshiftleft}
\setlength{\barshiftleft}{8pt}

\tcbset{
  defbarcolor/.colorlet=tcbcol@defbarcolor,
  exebarcolor/.colorlet=tcbcol@exebarcolor,
  chbaroptions/.style={enhanced,breakable,frame hidden, colback=white,after=\vskip0.4cm,size=tight,defbarcolor=green,exebarcolor=blue}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\exebar}{+O{}+m}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[chbaroptions,#1,
    underlay={\draw[tcbcol@exebarcolor,line width = 2pt] ($(frame.north west)-(\barshiftleft,0)$) -- ($(frame.south west)-(\barshiftleft,0)$);} ]
    \noindent\underline{Exemple :} {#2}%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\defbar}{+O{}+m}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[chbaroptions,#1,
    underlay={\draw[tcbcol@defbarcolor,line width = 2pt] ($(frame.north west)-(\barshiftleft,0)$) -- ($(frame.south west)-(\barshiftleft,0)$);} ]
    \noindent\underline{Définition :} {#2}%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{16}{16} \textbf{Chapitre 1 : Algèbre générale et arithmétique}
\end{center}

\hrule

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\section{Les groupes}

\subsection{Structure de groupe}

\defbar{\lipsum[2] \lipsum[2]}

\exebar[exebarcolor=violet]{\lipsum[2]}

\defbar{\lipsum[3-4]}

\exebar{\lipsum[4] \lipsum[6]}

\defbar{\lipsum[6] \lipsum[6]

Just another line.}

\subsection{Sous-groupe}

\defbar{Here is a new one-line text.

\begin{itemize}
\item The itemize that breaks it all.
\end{itemize}

Some extra-line.

\lipsum[5]
}

\exebar{Some property.}

\exebar{Some theorem.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile the code I get errors because of the letters with accents. I commented the `utf8` package line and the errors are now gone, and the accents are still alright; but is that the way it is supposed to be? Anyway, is there a reason why you put a '1' after the ':' of 'Exemple :' and 'Définition :'?

Comment: @Alex: The `1` are some remainder of a previous version. And actually you should save your files in `utf8` and not `ansinew` ...